# Is the adjective インディペンデント actually used as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, loanwords, compounds

I saw a movie labeled

> インディペンデント作品

The adjective インディペンデント does not end in *i* and is followed by neither *na* nor *no* here. Is this meant as a strange compound noun (*katakana* + *kanji*)? Or is this a partial translation of 'independent film', keeping the English grammar?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your example, インディペンダント is used as a noun indeed, a movie genre for example: "Independent".
You can compare with expressions such as ホラー映画.

The confusing part may be that there are also adjectives made from these same words, but their usage and meaning slightly differs: インディペンデントな働き方, ホラーなトイレットペーパー  (?!).